# Is there a splunk query to sum all the column values based on same row field?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard, splunk-calculation

I have a existing splunk table as:

| JobAction | Status | TimeTaken(ms) | Records | Host |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Delete | SUCCESS | 100 | 50 | Host1 |
| Delete | SUCCESS | 120 | 200 | Host1 |
| Insert | SUCCESS | 500 | 30 | Host1 |
| Insert | SUCCESS | 120 | 25 | Host1 |

I want to get the totaltime and totalrecords based on jobaction like as follows:

| JobAction | Status | Totaltime(ms) | TotalRecords | Host |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Delete | SUCCESS | 220 | 250 | Host1 |
| Insert | SUCCESS | 620 | 55 | Host1 |

---

I tried doing

|stats sum(Records) as TotalRecords by host,JobAction,Status

and was able to get total records but when i do the same for timetaken it's coming as empty.

Any suggestions on how to get total time and record both based on jobaction?

Answer (score 2):

Are you saying you tried `|stats sum("TimeTaken(ms)") as "Totaltime(ms)", sum(Records) as TotalRecords by host,JobAction,Status`?  Both calculations have to be done in the same `stats` command or you'll get empty results in the second `stats` call.  That's because `stats` is a transforming command that removes any fields it doesn't use or create so any subsequent `stats` call won't have the same fields to work with.

Comment: Yes, i tried that. It was only giving me total records and time as empty. I get it stats is a transforming command. Is there a non transforming substitute for that?

Comment: It should have worked, but won't if my assumptions about your field names don't match your reality.  Can you please share more of your query, specifically the part that creates the `TimeTaken(ms)` field?  The non-transforming alternatives to `stats` are `eventstats` and `streamstats`.  You probably want `eventstats`.